# Sencha Touch 2 Production

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am wondering why `sencha` production build not working in live server. I already tested the production build in my local then I upload it in my web server. It shows me 2 alert box.

1. **Requested:** `http://www.simplicity-gaming.net/mobile/resources/css/app.css` with checksum: `ac90c164209648c5e1b9e7c1569874b93174de3f` 
   but **received:** `dy,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,hinstead`. Attempt to refresh the application?
2. **Requested:** `http://www.simplicity-gaming.net/mobile/app.js` with checksum: `a159722373bb74a92d7f865503ea9b07faa9277c` but **received:** `unction(){var global=this,objectPrototinstead`. Attempt to refresh the application?

Here is my URL

http://www.simplicity-gaming.net/mobile

## PROBLEM SOLVED.

My webhost has Cloudflare and it has html and js minifier enabled. Disabling it solved my problem.

Comment: No error while compiling for production ?

Comment: Yes it doesnt have an error during compiling. I already tested the production build in my local it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Are the checksums in tact? Try viewing the source and verify if the server is not removing the comment